# Using repeater of master pages in its content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey I am new here and I am also aware of this community since last 6 months.
i have a question please tell me how can i access/use repeater control in content pages from master page. because of some dynamic layout I am using repeater in master page. I also need it in content pages. Instead of using individual repeaters in content pages can I use the repeater control of master page??? 
using asp.net with c#
thanks

Comment: `"access/use repeater control in content pages from master page"` - Generally a master page *shouldn't* be reaching into the properties of content pages.  Only the reverse should be true (content pages accessing properties of the master page).  Coupling a master page to a particular implementation of content pages would likely be a bad idea.

Comment: @Yousafzai so you mean...you need only layout from MasterPage?

Comment: yes that what i meant. but all the content pages have their respective list items from database. i am new to .net